# how to render a php page as a png image using data uri

Tags: php

I've the data uri of a png image, I've stored the data uri in mysql data base. Lets say img.php is the file that returns as a png image

```
<?php
  $id=$_GET['id];
  //data base connection and mysql queries
  $data = "data:image/png;base64,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"; 
  //$data is obtained from mysql database
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I've tried the above code, but its not giving me any output,
please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The code is mostly pointless. You already have a PNG inside the data uri, so there is exactly **ZERO** point in loading that PNG into GD, then re-compressing to a PNG. that's massive waste of RAM and CPU time to basically accomplish nothing.

Also, GD doesn't understand data uris, so you cannot feed this uri into GD functions and expect something useful to happen.

You already have a PNG, so all you need to do is basically this:

```
$b64_png = string_operation_to_extract_base64_data_from_data_uri($datauri);
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($b64_png);
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, But i didn't understand the first line,
i.e, string_operation_to_extract_base64_data_from_data_uri.

Comment: I'm a new to php, can you help me to resolve this. I've stored the data uri in mysql, what i want is to generate the png file as i call http://localhost/img/img.php?id=1. So I can use it in image tags as <img src"http://localhost/img/img.php?id=1" /> .

Comment: You can also save this image in a cache folder and verify first if the image was already requested and generated. Then, use XSendFile module from Apache or nginx to deliver the file if it exists, if not, save the file using an identifier for the next request. You will save some resources with this.